# CheckButton on tkinter is not "On" after setting the value

Tags: python, tkinter

I recently changed the geometry manager in my program from grid to pack because of a problem trying to get the Navigatiotoolbar in the frame.

The problem is that a check button that used to be on by default is not On by default now. Here is the code for the button:

```
    Var1=IntVar()
    Var1.set(1)
    c = tk.Checkbutton(self,text="Test", variable=Var1, onvalue=1,  offvalue=0)
    c.pack( side = LEFT )
```

So if I change the geometry manager I cannot longer put an ON default state?

Pd. The program runs without errors.

Here is a more complete piece of the code

```
class StartPage(tk.Tk):


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    Frame1 = Frame(self)
    Frame1.pack(side=TOP)

    Frame2 = Frame(self)
    Frame2.pack( side= TOP )

    Frame3 = Frame(self)
    Frame3.pack( side = TOP)

    Frame4 = Frame(self)
    Frame4.pack( side = BOTTOM , pady=20, expand=True)

    label = tk.Label(Frame1, text="Start Page")
    label.pack(side=TOP)

    button1=ttk.Button(Frame2, text="Visit Page 1",
                      command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageOne))
    button1.pack( side = LEFT )


    button2=ttk.Button(Frame3, text="Page Two",
                      command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageTwo) )
    button2.pack( side = LEFT )


    button3=ttk.Button(Frame2, text="Spider",
                      command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageThree) )
    button3.pack( side = LEFT )

    button4=ttk.Button(Frame2, text="Ternario",
                      command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageFour) )
    button4.pack( side = LEFT )

    button5=ttk.Button(Frame3, text="Ti-Zr-Yx3",
                      command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageFive) )
    button5.pack( side = LEFT )

    #global Var1

    Var1=IntVar()
    Var1.set(1)
    c = tk.Checkbutton(self,text="Test", variable=Var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    c.pack( side = LEFT )


app = StartPage()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The geometry manager has absolutely nothing to do with this problem. You must have changed or moved some other code around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `Var1` is being garbage collected at the end of the `__init__` function, making the Checkbutton forget its state before the window begins to render. One possible workaround is to save Var1 as an attribute of the instance, so it doesn't die prematurely.

```
    self.Var1=IntVar()
    self.Var1.set(1)
    c = tk.Checkbutton(self,text="Test", variable=self.Var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    c.pack( side = LEFT )
```

... Or just don't have an IntVar at all.

```
    c = tk.Checkbutton(self,text="Test")
    c.pack( side = LEFT )
    c.select()
```

Comment: It's not just `Var1` that's being garbage collected, it's every variable assigned in `__init__()`. They should all have `self.` prepended to their reference names so that they become instance variables.

Comment: Well, I expect the widgets themselves to not be garbage collected, because the `Tk` instance still "owns" them, as a result of `self` being the first argument of each of their constructors. The IntVar is a bit of an odd duck in not being part of the dependency graph, so to speak. If the OP doesn't need to refer to any of the widget variables after the method ends, it should be safe to not make them attributes of `self`.

Comment: That's why I said "should" and not "need to" - it may not be absolutely necessary, but saving every widget as an instance variable makes the code so much easier to manage.

Comment: Ok, agreed :-) It does make it easier to add functionality when you can access all your widgets anywhere inside the class definition.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, Worked like a charm :), I need the variable for tracing in my program thats why it is there. Again thanks

Answer (score 0):

The variable must be safe from garbage collection but also I think that you need the following code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk

def NewCheckbutton(frame, text, myvar, state, row, col):
   setit=myvar.get()
   c = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text=text, variable=myvar,
                      state=state)
   c.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="EW")
   c.select()
   c.toggle()
   print(f'Set={setit}')
   if setit:
     c.toggle()
   return c

root = Tk()

var1 = tk.IntVar()
#   self.var1 = var1
var1.set(0)
c1 = NewCheckbutton(root, text="One", myvar=var1, 
                    state="normal", row=0, col=0)
var2 = tk.IntVar()
#   self.var2 = var2
var2.set(1)
c2 = NewCheckbutton(root, text="Two", myvar=var2, 
                    state="normal", row=1, col=0)
#   ...
root.mainloop()
```